# Fuerte RGBD-SLAM for ASUS Action Pro

Tags: slam, ros-fuerte, xtion, rgbd-slam, asus

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

Is it possible to conduct an RGBD-SLAM using Fuerte for the ASUS Xtion Pro Live? If not how is this done?

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36324/fuerte-rgbd-slam-for-asus-action-pro/) by [BrowCam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2597/browcam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BrowCam](https://answers.ros.org/users/2597/browcam/) on 2012-06-12**:
Thanks I'll try it in Electric.
Is this easy enough in windows?
I'm constrained to windows 7 as the PC I'm using doesn't belong to me so changing the OS is out of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Generally, the Xtion Pro works as a drop in replacement for the Kinect without needing to modify anything. I haven't tried the Xtion pro in Fuerte, but in Electric, it works as expected with the included openni drivers. You should be able to follow the instructions on the RGBDSLAM wiki page as-is.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2